# Ubuntu 20.04 Performance on Raspi 3 B

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi

Will Ubuntu 20.04 work fine on a Raspi 3 B, or should I use 18.04 (except things won't be updated, and the EOL is in a few months)?

3B, 1GB of RAM

Comment: 18.04 is EOL April 2023. https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 will work fine on raspberry 3B

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi